# getting a spans html and displaying it in anothers with jquery

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

Maybe this is something simple, but after an hour of trial and error and searching i can not find anything. basically i have a table and each `<td>` has a `<span>` in it with an `id` of *day* and each has a number in it, you guessed it, for the days of the month. basically when a `<td>` is clicked on i want to grab that number and display it in another `<span>` with a `class` of *the date* from what i know of jquery im doing it properly. however on localhost i get the result:

```
[object Object]
```

which is obviously not a number. i tried recreating it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THUtq/3/) but that gives me nothing onclick.

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id = "day">3</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <span id = "day">8</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span class = "thedate">
    test
</span>
```

jquery:

```
    $('td').click(function(){
        var date = $('this').text('#day');
        $('.thedate').html(''+date+'');
    });
```

any ideas?

Comment: Two html elements cannot have the same id.

Comment: @Nick the specification explicitly disallows duplicate IDs

Comment: @Nick it *must* be unique ids,non unique IDs is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You forgot to load jQuery on your fiddle,

2) You are setting the text on that line, so the return value is the original jQuery object.

3) `$('this')` will select any HTML elements called `this`, like `<this />` you want `$(this)`

Try:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var date = $(this).find('span').text();
    $('.thedate').html(''+date+'');
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/THUtq/5/

Comment: youre a saint and a scholar.